# Postgresql. Optimize retriving distinct values from large table

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, distinct, postgresql-9.6

I have one de-normalized table with 40+ columns (~ 1.5 million rows, 1 Gb).

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (
  ...
  division_id integer,
  division_name varchar(10),
  ...
);
```

I need to speed up query

```
SELECT DISTINCT division_name, division_id 
FROM table 
ORDER BY division_name;
```

Query return only ~250 rows, but very slow cause size of table.

I have tried to create index:

```
create index idx1 on  tbl1 (division_name, division_id)
```

But current execution plan:

```
explain analyze SELECT Distinct division_name, division_id FROM tbl1 ORDER BY 1;

          QUERY PLAN                                                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Sort  (cost=143135.77..143197.64 rows=24748 width=74) (actual time=1925.697..1925.723 rows=294 loops=1)
Sort Key: division_name
    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 74kB
    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=141082.30..141329.78 rows=24748 width=74) (actual time=1923.853..1923.974 rows=294 loops=1)
             Group Key: division_name, division_id
             ->  Seq Scan on tbl1  (cost=0.00..132866.20 rows=1643220 width=74) (actual time=0.069..703.008 rows=1643220 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.311 ms
Execution time: 1925.883 ms
```

Any suggestion why index does not work or how I can speed up query in other way?

Server Postgresql 9.6.

p.s. Yes, table has 40+ columns and de-normalized, but I know all pros and cons for with decision.

**Update1**

@a_horse_with_no_name suggest to use vacuum analyze instead of analyze to update table statistic. Now query plain is:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                
------------------------
 Unique  (cost=0.55..115753.43 rows=25208 width=74) (actual time=0.165..921.426 rows=294 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using idx1 on tbl1  (cost=0.55..107538.21 rows=1643044 width=74) (actual time=0.162..593.322 rows=1643220 loops=1)
         Heap Fetches: 0
```

Much better!

Comment: obvious question, but you didnot mention it - you gathered stats after index creation - right?..

Comment: good suggestion, but "analyze  tbl1;" does not help - I got same query plan.

Comment: hm. well - you can off the seqcan and see the plan with index - just to make sure it is cheaper

Comment: Hmm, that _should_ use an index scan. Try a `vacuum analzye` on the table.

Comment: You may have better luck if you reverse the column order in your index to be `division_id, division_name`. Indexes are (by default unless explicitly defined otherwise) sorted ascending by each column, left-to-right. Integers are by nature easier to sort by, and a sorted data set is easier to get distinct values from.

Comment: @Scoots i'll try, but 1) index new structure, that hold copy of data, so order of columns does not mater. 2) I have order by division_name,  so this column must be first.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name is right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The index will probably only help if PostgreSQL chooses an “index only scan”, that means that it does not have to look at the table data at all.

Normally PostgreSQL has to check the table data (“heap”) to see if a row is visible for the current transaction, because visibility information is not stored in the index.

If, however, the table does not change much and has recently been `VACUUM`ed, PostgreSQL knows that most of the pages consist only of items visible for everyone (there is a “visibility map” to keep track of that information), and then it might be cheaper to scan the index.

Try running `VACUUM` on the table and see if that causes an index only scan to be used.

Other than that, there is no way to speed up such a query.

Comment: Yes, vacuum analzye helps.